# Hide Pages WooCommerce

Tags: plugins

I would like a condition such as the following:

1) User is logged. Select Page Shop and displays all content.
2) If user is not logged. Select Shop page, they are redirected to another page, for example Sign Up page.

I hope it is possible. I have tried many plugins but failed. At the moment the only one that works with WooCommerce is s2Member, but it is overkill for my purpose.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using

1) [is_shop](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_shop.html) fx

2) [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) action hook

3) [wp_safe_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) fx

```
add_action('template_redirect','ravs_shop_for_login_user');
function ravs_shop_for_login_user(){
  //check user in shop page and not login
  if( is_shop() && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );// enter your url here where you want to redirect page if user on shop page and not registered
}
```

**Note** paste this code in `functions.php`.currently visiter redirect to home page if not registered,provide any url in wp_safe_redirect fx where you want to user redirect.

Comment: Hello Ravs,
it works fine but I have a little problem with WPML and URL


1) Language site English. User selects Shop, redirect page is "mypagetest", then: http://testsite.com/mypagetest
Ok, it works.


2) Website Language Italian. User selects Shop, redirect page is: http://testsite.com/it/mypagetest
URL error

Comment: do you have live site ?

Comment: try this http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/home-page-link/

Comment: I'm sorry, It works, it was just a caching issue and I also updated the permalinks.

Thanks again for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Past this code in your Page.php file in your theme. it should do what you need.

```
<?php
if (is_page('shop') && is_user_logged_in()) { // right the title of the page intead the "shop"
     header('Location: wp-login.php?action=register');   // here you can add the url you want to redirect user to it
}
?>
```